# Mvc3 application to windowazure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I want to convert my MVC - 3 project to WindowAzure project. I downloaded SDK for VWD express 2010. Can anybody please guide to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you: [Migrating an Existing ASP.NET App to run on Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This TechEd 2010 Presentation on [Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to Build Applications That Run on Windows Azure](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2010/COS307) by Jim Nakashima should get you going

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you don't need to make any changes in your MVC application to move to Windows Azure. Once you have Azure SDK (June 2012) Installed, you will have an option with your Solution properties as "Add Windows Azure Cloud Service Project" to move your MVCx application to Windows Azure. There will not be any change to your main application, but this way your application will be part of Windows Azure Application and run as a Web Role there.

Now if your Azure Application is set as Startup project and if you run your application, this will launch your application in Windows Azure Emulator so you can test your MVCx application in Windows Azure Emulator.

Finally you would need to make necessary code changes (i.e. Database connection etc) to successfully run your application as Windows Azure Cloud Service in cloud. This is all depend on what kind of your application is and how you would want to run your application in cloud.